# Whats it called when a shirt has a rectangle that buttons on the front

Tags: single-word-requests

In a couple fictional universes I've seen this kind of design, where the shirt will have a piece of fabric on the front that buttons on both sides...

[image]
[image]
and I was wondering if it has a name?

Comment: Two words that came to mind are *bib* and *tabard* but I don't think either is ideal.

Comment: Another thought was dungarees which have a flap at the front but that doesn't work for superman. -- https://cdnd.lystit.com/photos/68bd-2014/04/24/zara-blue-washed-denim-dungarees-product-1-19470380-7-406456139-normal_large_flex.jpeg

Comment: Also called a shield front shirt, the bib front (see answer from @Oldbag below) shirt style is rumored to have become popular in the west largely because a good many cavalry soldiers continued to wear their bib front uniform shirts when they seeped west after (and during) the US Civil War. As with so many articles of western wear, the style is utilitarian: the front-buttoned placket offers the wearer greater protection from dust, wind, rain, snow and sun than split front or even solid front tunic-style shirts. The extra layer of cloth provides an additional barrier against the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the styles on your cartoon friends are an homage to the double-breasted, bib-front, Western (or, Cowboy) shirt - which is an iconic style (...fer tuff-guys).

Comment: So I wasn't far wrong with bib! Here's a picture -- http://www.vintagewesternwear.com/Rangewear-Men-s-Fireman-s-Bib-Shirt-4-COLORS.html

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd call it a...

> **dicky** - *a detached shirt front* [<sub><sup>(etymonline)</sup></sub>](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dicky)

...which the full OED says can also be spelt **dickey**. As @chasly comments below, it can also be called a **bosom** - googling **picture dickey shirt** found me this pic...

[image]

...which is actually on the Wikipedia page headed [Dickey (garment)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey_(garment)), where the text starts...

> *A **dickey** (alternatively written as **dickie** or **dicky** sometimes known in American English as a **tuxedo front** or **tux front**) is a type of false shirt-front - originally known as a **detachable bosom***.

Comment: I thought a dicky was a fake turtleneck you wear under a shirt.

Comment: I tried looking up *dicky shirt* and came up with this thing called a 'bosom'! -- http://www.blacktieguide.com/Vintage/Shirts/1910_Arrow_Donchester_per_ebay.JPG

Comment: @chasly: I hadn't heard it called a "bosom" before, but I just googled **picture dickey shirt** and found a very similar pic to yours. I'll add it to the answer.